# Nodejs: sequelize row query to bulk inserting on postgis

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, postgis

In my **nodejs** worker service i am using **sequelize** row query to insert bulk array to **postgresql** database. This is my array object that i want to inserted:

[image]

I am using `unnest` to extract object from my array but how could i select specific property from unset method ?
For test i just want to add nid so this is my method to bulk insert :

```
async function bulkInsert(datas) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let values = [];
    Object.keys(datas).forEach(key => {
      values.push(JSON.parse(datas[key]))
    });
    let strpgsql =
      `INSERT into  public."sub_data" ("nid") 
      VALUES ('unnest(${values.nid})')`
    sequelize.pgsql.query(strpgsql);
  });
}
```

When i run my method i got rhis error?

```
Executing (default): INSERT into  public."sub_data" ("nid") 
      VALUES ('unnest(undefined)')
sequelize.js:1187
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "unnest(undefined)"
```

> Note:
>   I have to use row query because i have to change wkt property into `geometry` type by this command `ST_GeomFromText('${req.wkt}' ,4326)`

Comment: You just want the `nid` values from each object in the array `values`? If so then just do `let values = Object.values(datas).map( v => JSON.parse(v)['nid'] )` in the first place. Then `values` is simply an array of the values from the `nid` keys. Which is what I presume you are after. You *could* just `.map(({ nid }) => nid)` on your existing `values`, but you may as well only extract what you want to begin with. See also [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Comment: not just nid ! there are a few fields but for testing i just used `nid1. I want to list of `v` in `.map( v =>`  insert into postgresql @NeilLunn

Comment: Not clear what you are asking then. You need to be more specific in the question. My point above is mainly that `values.nid` is not valid to extract just that value from an array of objects. You use `.map()` to extract specific values by a named key.

Comment: As you can see om my picture i have a list of object. how can i bulk insert list of object into database by row query? @NeilLunn